# Conky-manager failed to start

Tags: 19.10, conky

I'm using ubuntu 19.10. I want to customize my home screen, so I installed conky and conky manager. At first, the app runs very well but when later on I started to run the app again  it's showing an error as follows:

```
Error: Commands listed below are not available:
*import
Please install required packages and try running it again
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You will need to install the imagemagick package: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` as this contains the `import` application...

Comment: What is the connection between the two?

Comment: I have made a 'formal' answer and shown where the dependency is outlined in the installation deb file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package conky-manager has a few 'hard' dependencies that it requires to successfully run. This can be seen well enough in the [Debian control file](https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager/blob/master/debian/control) where the following dependencies are listed:

```
Depends: [...] realpath, conky, p7zip-full, rsync, imagemagick <---
```

(I have added the arrow and trimmed out some of the script to enhance readability). In your case conky-manager is complaining that it cannot access `import` which is one of a suite of applications that come with imagemagic.

Test if this is the case *on your system* by running the following:

```
andrew@ilium~$ import --version | head -n1
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-71 Q16 x86_64 2019-10-31 https://imagemagick.org
andrew@ilium~$
```

To bring conky-manager back to life simply run the following in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

And then all should be well...

**References:**

- [Playing Around with Conky on Gentoo](https://elatov.github.io/2016/01/playing-around-with-conky-on-gentoo/): A nice run-through concerning conky and the conky-manager. The `import` error is specifically mentioned along with the fix...

Comment: Thank you for your time and solution... It worked, but i want to know is there any way of uninstall imagemagick and keeping the import package?

Comment: @AshutoshDash I suspect that under Ubuntu this would be difficult. Perhaps post this as another question?